# Changing Mantissa's Width in Non-IEEE Floating Point implementation

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, floating-point-precision

I have a gcc cross compiler on an 18 bit soft-core processor target
that has the following datatypes defined:
Integer 18 bit, Long 36 bit and float 36-bit(single precision).
Right now my focus is on floating point operation. Since the width is
non-standard(36 bit), I have the following scheme: 27 bits for
Mantissa(significand), 8 bits for Exponents and 1 Sign bit.
I can see the widths are defined in the float.h file. of interest to
me are the following:
FLT_MANT_DIG  and FLT_DIG.
They are defined as:

FLT_MANT_DIG 24
FLT_DIG 6

I have changed them to

FLT_MANT_DIG 28
 FLT_DIG 9

As per my requirements in float.h and then build the gcc compiler. But
still I get 32 bit floating point output.Do anyone has any experience
implementing non-standard single precision floating point numbers
and/or know the workaround?

Comment: `FLT_DIG 9` is incorrect.  With 28 (27 explicit + 1 implied) bits of binary significand, use `FLT_DIG 8`.  "⎣(p − 1) log10 b⎦" C11dr §5.2.4.2.2 11

Comment: Please elaborate "still I get 32 bit floating point output."

Comment: BTW: If your FP is really non-standard, it might not use an implied MSBit, it which case use `FLT_MANT_DIG 27 FLT_DIG 7`.  Do you have a reference for that 36-bit FP type?

Comment: You have it backward.  The `float.h` constants describe the floating point format that the rest of the compiler assumes so that _your_ programs can use this information. Changing `float.h` will have absolutely no effect on the compiler itself.

Answer (score 1):

Efficient floating-point math requires hardware which is designed to support the exact floating-point formats which are being used.  In the absence of such hardware, routines which are designed around a particular floating-point format will be much more efficient than routines which are readily adaptable to other formats.  The GCC compiler and supplied libraries are designed to operate efficiently with IEEE-754 floating-point types and are not particularly adaptable to any others.  The aforementioned headers exist not to allow a programmer to *request* a particular floating-point format, but merely to notify code about what format is going to be used.

If you don't need 72-bit floating-point types, and if the compiler's `double` type will perform 64-bit math in something resembling sensible fashion even though `long` is 36 bits rather than 32, you might be able to arrange things so that `float` values get unpacked into a four-word `double`, perform computations using that, and then rearrange the bits of the `double` to yield a `float`.  Alternatively, you could write or find 36-bit floating-point libraries.  I would not particularly expect GCC or its libraries to include such a thing, since 36-bit processors are rather rare these days.